# Limit PivotTable Filter based on another filter

Tags: vba, excel

I have a pivot table with multiple filters, such as:

> Site: select one of the sites
>
> Supervisor: shows all supervisors, regardless of site

Currently, the Supervisor filter shows all the available options from the data set.  I want it to only display the supervisor names that match the selected site.  I'm trying to put together an automated solution that will update as users select the options they need within the filters (to see their site and individual teams, for example).  I'm trying to automate this, so it will always be current as supervisors are added/removed from the data set.

I'm pretty sure automating this is a VBA issue, but I'm pretty new to using VBA, so I'm not sure where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as I'm new and do not have enough rep to comment I will just give you an answer and if it's not what you're looking for I will remove it.

I don't believe this is a VBA issue. In the pivot table Field List you will want to set Supervisor to be filtered by clicking the little downward arrow beside the field name within the "Choose fields to add to report" box. That way when you select a site you can then filter out any of the supervisors that don't belong there.

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually looking for an automated solution that will update itself as the data changes.  I elaborated on the original question to make that more clear.

Comment: Could you post some sample data so that I can see what you are working with?